# Doctrine2 ORM does not save changes to a DateTime field

Tags: oop, doctrine-orm, encapsulation

I have a User entity:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ExampleBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="service_expires_at", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $service_expires_at;

    public function getServiceExpiresAt()
    {
        return $this->service_expires_at;
    }

    public function setServiceExpiresAt(\DateTime $service_expires_at)
    {
        $this->service_expires_at = $service_expires_at;
    }
}
```

When i update the User's `service_expires_at` as following, the updated `service_expires_at` value is **NOT** saved back into the database:

```php
$date = $user->getServiceExpiresAt(); 

var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d')); // 2013-03-08

$date->modify('+10 days');

var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d')); // 2013-03-18

$user->setServiceExpiresAt($date);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

However if i pass a new `DateTime` object to `service_expires_at`, the updated value is saved correctly:

```php
$date = $user->getServiceExpiresAt(); 

$date->modify('+10 days');

$user->setServiceExpiresAt(new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d'));

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The `DateTime` instances returned by `ExampleBundle\Entity\User#getServiceExpiresAt()`  are the same objects stored in the entity itself, which breaks [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

The [UnitOfWork in Doctrine ORM applies strict comparison for changesets](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L581-L584), which basically means that in the case of properties of entities containing objects, if the object instance hasn't changed, the ORM does not detect a change.

In strict comparison, following is true:

```php
$dateTime1 = new \DateTime('@0');
$dateTime2 = new \DateTime('@0');
$dateTime3 = $dateTime1;

var_dump($dateTime1 !== $dateTime2); // true
var_dump($dateTime1 === $dateTime3); // true

$dateTime1->modify('+1 day');

var_dump($dateTime1 === $dateTime3); // true
```

This is a very common mistake among newcomers in OOP programming, and it can be solved quickly by fixing your getters and setters so that the original instance is never shared outside of your object, like in following example:

```php
public function getServiceExpiresAt()
{
    return clone $this->service_expires_at;
}

public function setServiceExpiresAt(\DateTime $service_expires_at)
{
    $this->service_expires_at = clone $service_expires_at;
}
```

This will also fix your problem with Doctrine ORM.

Also, please note that this fixes possible leaks in your logic. For example, following code is buggy and hard to debug (when applying your currently broken getters/setters):

```php
$bankTransaction1 = $someService->getTransaction(1);
$bankTransaction2 = $someService->getTransaction(2);

// leak! Now both objects reference the same DateTime instance!
$bankTransaction2->setDateTime($bankTransaction1->getDateTime());

// bug! now both your objects were modified!
$bankTransaction1->getDateTime()->modify('+1 day');
```

So, regardless of the ORM part in the question, please don't  break encapsulation.

Comment: The answer is really detailed and points out the exact problem ! Thanks for the effort. This was driving me nuts !

Comment: You should take into account that this is not a good idea for all fields. If you've got a relationship between two entities cloning the object will trigger lazy-loading as soon as you touch the proxy. That could ruin your performance

Comment: Performance is almost always secondary in these scenarios: if you want performance out of this sort of operations, perform the copying operation at DB level directly (via `INSERT ... SELECT ...`)

Comment: I had the issue, and thought of wrapping persist-flush in transaction (`beginTransaction`/`commit`) - it worked.
Also - there was no problem in local env (xampp), only in prod linux. Could it be that this behavior depends on env-settings?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) class for your date/time properties. Thereby, note that *DateTimeImmutable is not an instance of DateTime*.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem when i am trying to insert an entity with a past date (i'm trying to migrate an old database to new schema with it's data too).

I tried to clone the object in both setter and getter and it's useless. Doctrine 2 saves the current date. Checked the schema, the field is date time not time stamp and default is null.

How can this be?

EDIT:

please excuse my lack of attention, my colleague dev added a prePersist event:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
function onPrePersist() {
    $this->created_at = new \DateTime('now');
}
```