# Doctrine modified DateTime is not persisted

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I try to modify DateTime field of the object with `modify` function

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $end = $session->getEndDate();
    $session->setEndDate($end->modify('+10 seconds'));
    $em->persist($session);
    $em->flush();
```

This is setter for $endDate field in Session class:

```
  /**
    * @param \DateTime $endDate
    */
   public function setEndDate(\DateTime $endDate)
   {
       $this->endDate = $endDate;
   }
```

Why end date changes can't be persisted to database?

Comment: You've posted as `$this->endDate = $eEndDate;` Should that instead be: `$this->endDate = $endDate;`???

Comment: yeah, thanks. that was typo

Comment: You need to `flush()` as per @Sofien's answer.

Comment: Wait - can you clarify are you already calling `flush()`???

Comment: As mentioned in your previous question on the exact same topic: $end = clone $session->getEndDate(); http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html#datetime-changes-are-detected-by-reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doctrine won't save changes to the existing DateTime instance (due to the internals of PHP's equality testing I think)

If you clone the object and then set it back, should work. Or clone it in the setter?

See [Doctrine2 ORM does not save changes to a DateTime field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486402/doctrine2-orm-does-not-save-changes-to-a-datetime-field)

Answer (score 3):

You need to flush it:

```
$em->flush($session);
```

The persist is only for entity not yet created.

UPDATE:

The `modify` method don't return anything, affect the specify object instance, so you can simply try:

```
$end = $session->getEndDate();
$end->modify('+10 seconds');
$em->flush();
```

Hope this help

Comment: I had flush there, forgot to include in question. DateTime still not persisted

Comment: Hi Matteo. `$session` shouldn't be a parameter of flush, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @AlvinBunk The flush method accept an entity instance to flush

Comment: @blahblah see my update

Comment: DateTime is still not updated in db. and I checked profiler, there is no `UPDATE session SET` query to update object

Comment: very strange... try debugging changing some other fields.... and see what happen in the profiler

Answer (score 1):

You need to add merge or flush to save the update

```
 $end = $session->getEndDate();
 $session->setEndDate($end->modify('+10 seconds'));
 $em->persist($session);
 $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Cerad 's comments, I wonder if this will work for you:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$end = new \DateTime( $session->getEndDate() );
$end->modify('+10 seconds');
$session->setEndDate( $end );
$em->persist($session);
$em->flush();
```

Can you try it out. I'm not certain it will make a difference though.